# Error compiling Facebook sdk

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am building an app and need to include login with facebook.
I have included facebook module sucessfully
But i am stuck at two alternatives

If i use     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.2'
then when i try to create button I gives no class found error

and If i try to link module to project and compile facebook sdk it gives error like this

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :facebook:generateDebugSources, :facebook:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileLint
:facebook:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:checkReleaseManifest
:facebook:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library
:facebook:prepareReleaseDependencies
:facebook:compileReleaseAidl
:facebook:compileReleaseRenderscript
:facebook:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:facebook:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseAssets
:facebook:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseResources
:facebook:mergeReleaseResources
:facebook:processReleaseManifest
:facebook:processReleaseResources
:facebook:generateReleaseSources
:facebook:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:facebook:extractReleaseAnnotations
:facebook:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseJar
:facebook:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseResources
:facebook:bundleRelease
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebook412Library
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk412Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(12844067): C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Kothians\app\src\main\res\drawable\ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(4465788): C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Kothians\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(9380663): C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Kothians\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(12572355): C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Kothians\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Kothians\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\com_facebook_button_icon.png: error: Duplicate file.
C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Kothians\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi\com_facebook_button_icon.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'A:\Programming Softwares\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 19.918 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

How to solve this error

Comment: I think Facebook sdk in on version 4.0.0. Have you tried `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'`?

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to generate the button?

Comment: You've likely figured this out by now... But I had this same issue and resolved it. The Facebook docs for adding their sdk are a bit confusing and if you build the SDK as a module/library AND have the compile 'com.facebook.android.facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0' in your build.gradle, you'll have redundancies. The solution is to remove one of the two in the gradle file, clean, and rebuild.